# Django rest framework charfilter json

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I have a filter in django rest charfilterinfilter(field_name= 'genres__name', lookup_expr= 'in').I have in the database is which two categories to approach I through Many To Many did ,But I have when filtrating two categories of this product there are two elements I need only one element

views

```
class CharFilterInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
    pass

class ShoppFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    price = filters.RangeFilter()
    genres = CharFilterInFilter(field_name='genres__name')
    title = SearchFilter()
    class Meta:
        model = smartphone
        fields = ['price','genres','title']


class MDShopListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = smartphone.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter)
    search_fields = ['title']
    filterset_class = ShoppFilter



def get(self, request):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    serializer=MDShopListSerializer(queryset,many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

models

```
genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, verbose_name="жанры")


class Genre(models.Model):
   [enter image description here][1]
    name = models.CharField("Имя", max_length=100)
```

img  json
1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WR6L.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WR6L.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here change and work
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).distinct()

```
class CharFilterInFilter(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
        pass

class ShoppFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    price = filters.RangeFilter()
    genres = CharFilterInFilter(field_name='genres__name', lookup_expr='in')
    title = SearchFilter()
    

    class Meta:
        model = smartphone
        fields = ['price','genres','title']


class MDShopListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = smartphone.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,SearchFilter)
    search_fields = ['title']
    filterset_class = ShoppFilter

    
    
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).distinct()
        serializer=MDShopListSerializer(queryset,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a usual problem with ManyToMany fields, solution would be to apply a `distinct` method to the query:

```py
class ShoppFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    ...your filter definition as it is now

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        return super(ShoppFilter, self).filter_queryset(
            request, queryset, view
        ).distinct()
```

Comment: here change and work
queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset()).distinct()